# Build GL application with CMake, GLEW_DIR and GLFW_DIR not set

Tags: macos, cmake, glfw, glew, pkg-config

I'm trying to build a demo depending on GLEW and GLFW on macOS. I have installed GLEW and GLFW with `brew` and they both locate under `/usr/local/Cellar`. Then I use CMake to locate dependencies and my codes are as follows:

```
# for GLEW
set(GLEW_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.1.0/lib/cmake/glew)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED PATHS ${GLEW_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
message(STATUS ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR})
# for GLFW
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
message(STATUS ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

But as a result the first `message` always prints `/usr/local/include` and the second prints nothing. What's the problem with my CMake code? Thanks.

Comment: Variable `GLEW_DIR` affets only on `find_package(GLEW)` and doesn't affect on `pkg_search_module(GLFW)`. If you previous search has resulted in `/usr/local/include` as include directory, this value remains until clearing the cache (`CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory).